# PHP-FPM error log /var/log/fpm-php.www.log Which system user writes the file?

Tags: permissions, php, logs, php-fpm

PHP-FPM error log is saved to `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`.

Which system user writes to this file?

The file permissions are set to this:

```
$ sudo chmod 666 /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
```

I would like to change it to:

```
$ sudo chmod 604 /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
```

I don't know which system user wrote `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log` file.

```
$ sudo chown ?:? /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
```

I don't know the system user and system group to enter in "?:?" Of the above command.

#### This question was self-solved by me:

```
$ sudo vi /var/www/html/myerrortest.php
```

```
<?php
    ini_set("error_log", "/var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt");
    error_log("PHP_error_log_write_test".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n\n\n");
?>
```

```
$ sudo touch /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt
$ sudo chmod 604 /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt
```

Access the following URL in my Firefox browser: `localhost/myerrortest.php`

```
$ less /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt
```

I could output error log permission `604`. This Question's Answer is `www-data`.

Comment: What are the current owner and group of the file ? Why do you want to change it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Generally this would be `root:adm` unless you're doing something very specific with your PHP installation ...

Comment: This question was self-solved by me.

$ sudo vi /var/www/html/myerrortest.php

<?php ini_set("error_log", "/var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt"); error_log("PHP_error_log_write_test”.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').”\n\n\n"); ?>

$ sudo touch /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt
$ sudo chmod 604 /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt

Access the following URL in my Firefox browser.

http://localhost/myerrortest.php

$ less /var/log/my_php-fpm_error_log.txt

I could output error log permission 604.

This Question's Anser is
www-data